# Convert festival tts to flite tts

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, festival, flite

i currently have a tts which is built using festival and festvox. i need to convert these voices and build a TTS in flite. apparently you can do the conversion using festvox (the festvox and flite websites say so but no proper steps on how to do it). can some one please help me out with it as i am new to this area?
thanx in advance ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in-case anyone else was wondering the same i found the steps mentioned in [this document](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/doc/flite_8.html) useful and also subscribe to the mailing lists and feel free to ask question.

although i must mention i never implemented to TTS using "flite". i went ahead with "espeak"